# What is Caret-At (^@) under emacs?

Tags: emacs, redirection, newlines

I'm use to seeing Caret-M (^M) under Emacs. But below, I'm seeing Caret-At (^@):

[image]

The file was created by running the [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) test program on OpenBSD with the command `./cryptest.exe > cryptopp.txt`. The odd thing is, all the lines in the file were created with C++'s `endl`. And `endl` is sensitive to the platform's end-of-line, so it gets things like `CR` and `LF` correct.

It seems like Caret-At (^@) should be everywhere or nowhere.

What is the Caret-At (^@), and why is it only showing up on the first line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### What is the Caret-At (^@)?

It is a null character (control-@, or ASCII 0) which emacs displays as `^@`.

---

#### Why is it only showing up on the first line?

Because `cryptest` outputs them at this point.

---

> Most characters are printing characters: when they appear in a buffer,
>   they are displayed literally on the screen. Printing characters
>   include ASCII numbers, letters, and punctuation characters, as well as
>   many non-ASCII characters.
>
> The ASCII character set contains non-printing control characters. Two
>   of these are displayed specially: the newline character (Unicode code
>   point U+000A) is displayed by starting a new line, while the tab
>   character (U+0009) is displayed as a space that extends to the next
>   tab stop column (normally every 8 columns). The number of spaces per
>   tab is controlled by the buffer-local variable tab-width, which must
>   have an integer value between 1 and 1000, inclusive. Note that how the
>   tab character in the buffer is displayed has nothing to do with the
>   definition of TAB as a command.
>
> Other ASCII control characters, whose codes are below U+0020 (octal
>   40, decimal 32), are displayed as a caret (`^`) followed by the
>   non-control version of the character, with the escape-glyph face. For
>   instance, the <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> character, U+0001, is displayed as `^A`.

Source [14.19 How Text Is Displayed](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Display.html)

Comment: Oh, OK, I see. I know exactly where its coming then. I went down a rabbit hole because I thought it was a line ending....